# Debian searching for available packages - unsorted list

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, debian, package

Is there a way to get a list of available packages (that can be installed), but to get the output unsorted? I've tried apt-cache search, but it sorts the output.

Comment: why do you want an unsorted list?

Comment: Um, if they're not to be sorted alphabetically, what order *do* you want them in? This question is like going to McDonald's and ordering "not a cheeseburger".

Comment: ... and also 'apt-cache search' do not sort the output.

Comment: In judging policies we should consider the results that have been achieved through them rather than the means by which they have been executed.

Comment: @Robertfrost I've been staring at your comment for a full 60 seconds now, and still have not the slightest clue what you're getting at.

Comment: Well, because it is a bit Machiavellique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be at fault because I should have said "packages that apt knows". The answer is apt-cache pkgnames.